# How does pubsub know how many messages I published at a point in time?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

Code for publishing the messages here:

```js
async function publishMessage(topicName) {
  console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] publishing messages`);
  const pubsub = new PubSub({ projectId: PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID });
  const topic = pubsub.topic(topicName, {
    batching: {
      maxMessages: 10,
      maxMilliseconds: 10 * 1000,
    },
  });

  const n = 5;
  const dataBufs: Buffer[] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const data = `message payload ${i}`;
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);
    dataBufs.push(dataBuffer);
  }

  const results = await Promise.all(
    dataBufs.map((dataBuf, idx) =>
      topic.publish(dataBuf).then((messageId) => {
        console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] Message ${messageId} published. index: ${idx}`);
        return messageId;
      })
    )
  );
  console.log('results:', results.toString());
}
```

As you can see, I am going to publish 5 messages. The time to publish is `await Promise.all(...)`, I mean, for users, We can say send messages at this moment, but for internal of pubsub library maybe not. I set `maxMessages` to `10`, so pubsub will wait for 10 seconds(`maxMilliseconds`), then publish these 5 messages.

The exuection result meets my expectations:

```sh
[2020-05-05T09:53:32.078Z] publishing messages
[2020-05-05T09:53:42.209Z] Message 36854 published. index: 0
[2020-05-05T09:53:42.209Z] Message 36855 published. index: 1
[2020-05-05T09:53:42.209Z] Message 36856 published. index: 2
[2020-05-05T09:53:42.209Z] Message 36857 published. index: 3
[2020-05-05T09:53:42.209Z] Message 36858 published. index: 4
results: 36854,36855,36856,36857,36858
```

In fact, I think `topic.publish` does not directly call the remote pubsub service, but pushes the message into the memory queue. And there is a window time to calculate the count of the messages, maybe in a tick or something like:

```js
// internal logic of @google/pubsub library
setTimeout(() => {
  // if user messages to be published gte maxMessages, then, publish them immediately
  if(getLength(messageQueue) >= maxMessages) {
    callRemotePubsubService(messageQueue)
  }
}, /* window time = */ 100);
```

Or using `setImmediate()`, `process.nextTick()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the conditions for sending a message to the service is an OR not an AND. In other words, if either `maxMessages` messages are waiting to be sent OR `maxMilliseconds` has passed since the library received the first outstanding message, it will send the outstanding messages to the server.

The [source code for the client library](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub) is available, so you can see exactly what it does. The library has a queue that it uses to track messages that haven't been sent yet. When a message is added, if the queue is now full (based on the batching settings), then it [immediately calls publish](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/2e973a55008c4d50ef3f7d47ac4ba761cd2ea9cb/src/publisher/message-queues.ts#L125). When the first message is added, it [uses `setTimeout`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/2e973a55008c4d50ef3f7d47ac4ba761cd2ea9cb/src/publisher/message-queues.ts#L128) to schedule a call that ultimately [calls publish on the service](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/2e973a55008c4d50ef3f7d47ac4ba761cd2ea9cb/src/publisher/message-queues.ts#L78). The publisher client [has an instance of the queue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/blob/2e973a55008c4d50ef3f7d47ac4ba761cd2ea9cb/src/publisher/index.ts#L66) to which it adds messages when `publish` is called.

Comment: I found some description about how it works from google-pubsub-python doc: https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/publisher/index.html#batching